# Non-linear optimization (linear constraints with discontinuities)

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find the optima for the following problem:

$$ max_{x_1,x_2} f(x_1, x_2)$$ where the constraint is:

$$ x_1 = a - b * x_2 * \mathbb{1}\{0<x_2\leq k\} - c * x_2 * \mathbb{1}\{x_2> k\}$$

where $a,b,c, x_1, x_2, k$ are positive real numbers. How does one go about finding the optima of such problems where the linear constraints have discontinuities? Are there any established results? I was wondering if we can always perform the following steps:

1. Assume $x_2^*\leq k$ and solve the problem for $x_2^*$
2. Assume $x_2^*>k$ and solve the problem for $x_2^*$

Compare the two $x_2^*$ and select the higher one. Is this correct? Would this algorithm always work if $f$ is concave in both arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have partitioned the feasible region into two disjoint sets.  Solving these two subproblems independently and taking the better solution is optimal, no matter what properties $f$ satisfies.